# Shared Inventory on Associated Products in a Configurable Product

Tags: magento-1.9

Let's say I'm selling necklaces using a certain stone, and the customer has the option to have it done it either silver or gold chain, with the fancy addons or just plain. I have it set up as a configurable product, where they choose the chain and the fanciness. The limiting factor for supply is the stone, which may never come back in stock after it's used up. How can I have the associated products (Stone-Fancy-Silver, Stone-Fancy-Gold, Stone-Plain-Silver, Stone-Plain-Gold) share the same inventory, so that whenever one of them is purchased, the inventory goes down by 1 for all of them?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a work for configurable products.

Configurable products are used when **your simple proucts are distinct stock units** with **distinct availability**.

The typical example of configurable products are shoses, where you have different colors and sizes inside a single product's page, but each combination represents a different product.

What you are looking for is more like a **simple product with options**.

Just create a simple product and add custom options from the left tab.

You will let you customer choose the color they like, but the stock unit will be only one with only one quantity to handle.

Hope it helps you.